# Cannot connect to ODBC DSN

Tags: mysql, powershell, odbc

I want to connect to my ODBC DSN but I always get an error

```
$conn = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=k1000.ad.bac.work;Database=KACE;User=usr;Password=pwd;Option=3"

$conn.Open()

if($conn.Open() -eq $true){
    Write-Host "Connection is open"
}

else{
    Write-Host "Connection failed"
}
```

Name       : KACE
DsnType    : System
Platform   : 32-bit
DriverName : MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver

Error MSG:Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'usr'@'%' to database 'KACE'

My goal is to get the entire table of a DB in a csv file scripted.

Comment: What error do you always get?

Comment: 1. Could you please verify the that the "KACE" DSN is defined as such and is accessible from your script by adding the following code:
`$DSN = 'KACE';
& {
  $OldDebugPreference = $DebugPreference;
  $DebugPreference = 'Continue';

  $DSNs = Wdac\Get-OdbcDsn;
  $DSNs | Write-Debug;
  if ($DSN -cin $DSNs.Name) {
    Write-Debug "SUCCESS: A DSN named '$DSN' exists and is accessible."
  } else {
    Write-Debug "FAILURE: A DSN named '$DSN' does not exist or is not accessible."
  };

  $DebugPreference = $OldDebugPreference
}
`

Comment: If the DSN turns out to be _not_ defined, then check that it was actually defined in the correct place / under the **exact** name / with the right permissions / etc.  If all those things are already true, then I suspect that the user / environment / etc. under which the script is being run is different than your interactive user / environment / etc. that you used to create the ODBC DSN.  If that is not the case, then see my next recommendation below:

Comment: Replace `$conn.connectionstring = "(DSN=$DSN)"` with `$conn.ConnectionString = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder] @{ DataSource = $DSN }`.

Comment: Still the same error @Travis Debug result: DEBUG: MSFT_OdbcDsn (DsnType = "System", Name = "KACE", Platform = "32-bit")
DEBUG: SUCCESS: A DSN named 'KACE' exists and is accessible.

Comment: Using a predefined DSN on local machine, I was able to reproduce your issue with you original code, and was just now able to fix the issue using my second proposal (to let `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` do the connection string formatting for you).  @claeys Please let me know if it fixes the issue on your end or not so I can either post a proper answer or keep researching.

Comment: Could you send me the usage or an example of the class please?

Comment: @Travis updated the code above still same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203673/discussion-between-claeys-and-travis).